# What are some online e-TAX filing platform in India?

Tags: income-tax

e-TAX payment procedure in India.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Income tax Department's [site](https://www.incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/) to file your returns. For most use cases, it is the best option especially if you dont want to trust third party sites.